# mongoose not saving documents

Tags: node.js, csv, mongoose

I'm trying to save some documents using node.js/mongoose.

I retrieve the data from a csv file and use the csv module to import the data.

Somehow it says all the records are saving correctly to the DB but when I open it through 'mongo' command and parse the DB no info has been saved at all.

This is the code I'm using:

```
//import.js
var csv = require('csv');
var mongoose=require("mongoose"),
db = mongoose.createConnection('127.0.0.1','camelot');

db.on('error',function(){
console.error.bind(console,'conection error');
console.log("Error al crear conexion");
});
db.once('open',function(){
console.log("DB open")
// Definicion de jugador
var playerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nombre: String,
    alianza: String,
    correo: String,
    poder: Number,
    nivel: Number,
    villa1: {
        nombre: String,
        x: Number,
        y: Number
    },
    villa2: {
        nombre: String,
        x: Number,
        y: Number
    }
});
var jugador = db.model('jugador',playerSchema);
csv().fromPath('datos.csv',{columns: ['timestamp', 'nombre','alianza','x','y','nivel','poder','notas']})                                                
.on('end',function(count){
    console.log('Lineas:'+count)
})
// --> PARSEO DE CADA LINEA DEL CSV <--//   
.on('data',function(data,index){
    var j = new jugador({ nombre: data.nombre });
    j.save(function (err){
        if(err){
            console.log('Error al escribir en la DB');
        }else
        {
            //console.log("Guardado: "+data.nombre);
        }
    })
})
});`
```

Comment: after investigating quite a bit more I can see a collection 'jugadors' has been created in the DB with all the imported data. I set the connection to localhost/camelot. Shouldnt a 'Camelot' collection been created with the data?

Comment: As used in your code, 'Camelot' is the name of the database and 'jugadors' is the name of the collection within that database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose pluralizes model name by default. You can set collection name manually by passing third argument to db.model if you need this:

```
var jugador = db.model('jugador',playerSchema, 'jugador');
```

Comment: thanks, could find the collection, but that third parameter is very informative :)